# Hyperlink to file In Excel OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive

I have some pdf documents I want to have links in my excel file. All these pdfs are on one drive. Is there away I can hyperlink them?

I made a hyperlink and I can access the files but when I connect them and go to another computer the link does not work.

Comment: Do you have access to those files from the other computer (Does the link works if you just paste in a browser in the other pc)? Did you specified in the link the documents' web address, or their location on your pc's synced folder?

Comment: It is not the physical link to anything on my pc. It is some weird link that does not look valid(if I copy and paste it in it does not even think it is a link and tries to search google). The weird thing though when I edit the hyperlink on another computer it seems to know which folder it came from on my onedrive as I see everything in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

Link to a pdf file deeper in the folder structure, relatively to the Excel file.

In a cell, lets say A8:
=LEFT(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("[",CELL("filename",A1))-1)
(In outher countrys the above has to be translated to your language.)
(Try to google Excel path in your language.)

In a cell, lets say B8:
="MyFolder1\MyFolder2\MyFile.pdf"

In a cell, lets say C8
=A8&B8

In a cell, leys say D8
=HYPERLINK(C8;"This is my link")

Hope this helps someone.